# Calculate Frequency Count for each statement in the following code

Tags: c, algorithm

How do I calculate the frequency count of each statement (i.e. the number of time each statement gets read/executed) in the following C code.
The frequency count of each statement must be written in terms of 'n'.

```
int dividable(int n){
   for(int i=3 ;i< = n ; i+=3)  
   if(n%i = 0){  
     cout << (“dividable\n”);
     return 0;
   }
 return 1;
}
```

Comment: You step thru the code line by line on a piece of paper or in a debugger.

Comment: The statements will be executed zero times because the code shown will not compile. `i< = n` is not a valid expression. In `n%i = 0`, `n%i` is not an lvalue so it is not a valid left operand of the assignment operator `=`. Below that, `cout` is not defined (particularly because this is C code but `cout` is a C++ thing). Each of these errors prevents compilation.

Comment: It is pretty undefined what is meant as a statement, here. Do you mean a keyword like for, int, if etc. or do you mean sequence points or is the for (...) treated as one statement or 4 statements?

Comment: @pqans: What is a statement is fully defined by the C grammar, and there would be no question about what the statements are in a well-formed C program.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the code is corrected, changing `< =` to `<=`, `n%i = 0` to `n%i == 0`, and `cout` to `printf`:

```
int dividable(int n)
{
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i += 3)  
        if (n%i == 0)
        {  
            printf("dividable\n");
            return 0;
        }
    return 1;
}
```

If `n` is less than 3, the `for` is executed once but immediately completes without executing any iterations of the body of the loop.

Otherwise, in the first iteration of the loop, `i` is 3. Then if `n` is a multiple of 3, `n%i` is 0, the `if` test is satisfied, and the routine prints “dividable” and returns 1.

If `n` is not a multiple of 3, then `n%i` is never 0, because `i` is always a multiple of 3. Then the test is never satisfied, all loop iterations are executed, and the routine returns 0.

Thus we have:

- If `n` is less than 3, the `for` is executed once, the `return 1;` is executed once, and the other statements are executed zero times.
- Otherwise, if `n` is a multiple of 3, the `for` is executed once (partially), the statements starting with `if`, `{`, `printf`, and `return 0;` are executed once each, and the `return 1;` is executed zero times.
- Otherwise, the `for` is executed once, the `if` is executed floor(`n`/3) times, the statements inside the `if` are executed zero times, and the `return 1;` is executed once.